# How do I make Google Service Account Credentials last forever?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am currently developing an android application that makes use of Dialogflow and I am calling the chat bot in app via downloading the credentials JSON file. I was told that the keys do not last forever and there will come a time when Im not able to connect with my chatbot and I will need to reset it manually. Is there any way or third-party program I can go about doing this and implementing it to my personal project? Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: What reference do you have that the keys don't last forever? As far as I know, keys don't expire - although you can cancel the keys yourself.

Comment: I was told by people saying how it will expire after maybe like 30 days and that I have to make some kind of code to make it constantly update which baffles me cause I thought Im able to just download the key and it should last forever.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, private keys from Google Cloud do not expire. The tokens they generate *do* frequently expire, but you are probably using a library that will read the private key to generate a new token when necessary.

You can *revoke* a key, thus making the copy that has been downloaded invalid, but that is a process that you control.

If you "were told" otherwise - ask for concrete referenes.

Comment: No problem! I was told by my teacher that it will 100% not work after a while if I have downloaded the keys to link up with my chatbot but I was confused as I was fairly certain as well that the dialogflow agent will still be able to be in the app for however long it may be.

Comment: If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.